# I am trying to print all of the logged-in users tasks from a file(tasks.txt) in a more user-friendly manner. This is what I have so far

Tags: python, file

I am trying to print all of the logged-in users tasks from a file(tasks.txt) in a more user-friendly manner.

```
def view_mine():

    print("My Tasks")
                    
    # Read the task from task.txt file
    with open ('tasks.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
                        
    # Check if the username of the person logged in is the same as the username you have read from the file
    loginUsername = user_login
    userTasks = [line for line in lines if line.lstrip().startswith(loginUsername)]
    print(''.join(userTasks))
```

Comment: so there should be only one match I guess ?

Answer (score 0):

first you have to define userligin in line 8
or if it is string you have to put it  in "" i hope that works for you